# Dynamically adding fragments from different sources

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have `MainActivity` which is going to act as a container to hold two fragments; `MainActivity` is a subclass of `FragmentActivity`. The top fragment is a fragment with just a `Spinner` which is declared as an inner class in `MainActivity`:

```
public static class NavigationFragment extends Fragment {

    public NavigationFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_fragment, container, false);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.menuSpinner);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.menuArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((MainActivity)getActivity());

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

When `MainActivity` is loaded, I successfully get my top fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.mainContainer, new NavigationFragment())
                .commit();

    }
}
```

The bottom fragment is the issue. In another file, I have `FragmentA` which doesn't really do much yet, but has some ui elements to see if its working; it's a subclass of `Fragment`. When the user changes the spinner's value, `FragmentA` will be removed and replaced with `FragmentB`. I'm trying to add the initial fragment it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.mainContainer, new NavigationFragment())
                .add(R.id.mainContainer, new FragmentA()) // THIS IS THE ONLY NEW LINE AND CAUSES THE ERROR
                .commit();

    }
}
```

I'm getting the error `can't resolved method add(int, com.mybundle.myapp.FragmentA)`. I don't understand why, because adding `NavigationFragment` should be the same as adding `FragmentA` as they both extend `Fragment`

My question is, how do I properly dynamically add, then replace, fragments that are not inner classes of the main activity that holds them?

And my other question is, is this the proper way to achieve this kind of navigation flow? I've been working with iOS for several years, so the shift to Android is a little foreign to me as far as design and navigation patterns.

Comment: why you have two 'add' to same container? first one can be add if container has no fragment yet, second one should be replace because container already one fragment.

Comment: I'm using add because I want both fragments on the screen. Wouldn't `replace` replace an existing fragment? Or do I not understand how this works?

Comment: why not use two seperate containers? then you do not need replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your definition files and make sure you use the same import for `FragmentTransaction` everywhere since `FragmentTransaction` API comes with the support version also to support android devices running 3.0 version and older

Comment: This also doesn't work, results in the same error. But, I also get a different error on the first line of your block. It's telling me that `beginTransaction()` returns `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` where `FragmentTransaction` is from `android.app.FragmentTransaction`. But when I change the type to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` by auto-fixing, that's when I get the same error as earlier

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, try `ft.replace()` for the second transaction and see if it works. You got the other error was because you are using the support version of `FragmentTransaction`, but imported it from `android.app.FragmentTransaction`

Comment: Ok. I fixed my imports to all be support now. Which should I be using, app or support?

Comment: Use the support version if you want to support devices running Android versions before 3.0 API level 11. Could you post the entire error message cos you can issue multiple transactions before commiting. This is really weird.

Comment: I just updated the question with the full error message. third paragraph from the bottom

Comment: When you used `ft.replace()`, did you pass it the same arguments as you did for the `ft.add()` method?

Comment: Yeah, I just replaced the word `add` with `replace`

Comment: Check the definition of your `FragmentA` and see if you used the correct imported package, make sure you use the support package everywhere

Comment: Looks like I didn't import the right one. I just auto imported everything and assumed it should work. It's working now. Wanna update your answer with this solution so I can mark it off? Thanks a lot for you help man

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks. And you are welcome. Glad to help.